# Exchange 2003 internal to external

Tags: exchange-2003

SBS exchange 2003

An internal user is trying to send an email to another user on the same domain but the 2nd user in not in the AD or in exchange but exchange gives a NDR without sending the email to the mail provider.

How can i get exchange to send the email to the mailprovider without adding the 2nd user to the AD and/or exchange?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set up SMTP namespace sharing. Here's an article that explains how to do it in Exchange Server 2003:

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/exchange-2003-smtp-namespace-sharing.html